# Does Lego Star Wars: The Freemaker Adventures contain spoilers for The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lego, lego-star-wars

Does the new (2016) Disney TV series *Lego Star Wars: The Freemaker Adventures* contain spoilers for *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*?

Let me explain the motivation for this question.

[*Darths & Droids*](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/) is a screencap webcomic based on the *Star Wars* films and parodying it.  The webcomic currently covers the first five episodes of *Star Wars* and most of the sixth, and will complete the sixth in a few months.

Now *Darths & Droids* might be continued to cover the seventh episode, *The Force Awakens*, or it might not: the creators of the comic haven't yet decided.  But since it's possible that it will cover *The Force Awakens*, the creators have [brought up the idea](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=144500#144500) that a volunteer could try to avoid spoilers for *The Force Awakens* film, and experience it from the comic strip first, before watching it.

> And since there's no such thing as an idea too stupid for the Internet...

This is, of course, very difficult, for *Star Wars* is very popular, and there are spoilers everywhere out there that the volunteer would have to try to avoid for a long interval (between two years and five years).

Anyway, Keybounce volunteered as the test subject provisionally, for he is still unspoiled about the movie.  But now he asked [a question](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=157684#157684).

> Ok, there is a new lego star wars on Disney. It features freemakers and cloud city. Is this spoiling episode 7?

You may answer here or in the *Darths & Droids* forum thread, I can relay the answer.  In either case, please keep your answer free of spoilers for *The Force Awakens*.  I've seen the film, but this question is mostly of interest to those who haven't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are **no** spoilers for Star Wars 7: The Force Awakens (thus far...)

[LEGO Star Wars: The Freemaker Adventures](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Freemaker_Adventures) is set in the years 3-4ABY, between the end of Star Wars: Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back and the start of Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi. As such, there's very limited scope for TFA spoilers. **At the time of writing there have been no crossover characters, no anachronisms and no in-jokes relating to TFA in any of the five episodes released**

> StarWars.com is thrilled to announce LEGO Star Wars: The Freemaker
> Adventures, an all-new animated television series scheduled to debut
> this summer on Disney XD in the US. The fun-filled adventure comedy
> series, set between The Empire Strikes Back and Return of the Jedi,
> will introduce all-new heroes and villains in exciting adventures with
> many familiar Star Wars characters.
>
> <sub><sup>[LEGO STAR WARS: THE FREEMAKER ADVENTURES ANIMATED SERIES COMING TO DISNEY XD THIS SUMMER](http://www.starwars.com/news/lego-star-wars-the-freemaker-adventures-animated-series-coming-to-disney-xd-this-summer)</sup></sub>

That being said, there are **massive** spoilers for films 1-6. Be warned.

Comment: and, given Lego's existing work with this license, they won't waste an opportunity to try and land a joke, no matter how 'spoilery' it might be considered

Comment: @NKCampbell - My gut instinct is that if they haven't dropped a TFA reference by five episodes in, they aren't going to at all.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - Oops. Editing fail on my part. I meant to put 3-5ABY. I've corrected it